# AJAX response doesn't run any script

Tags: ajax

My page gets a response from `response_ajax.php` with this code:

```
<input class="btn" name="send_button" type="button" value="check"
  onClick=
    "xmlhttpPost('/response_ajax.php',
    'MyForm',
    'MyResult',
    '<img src=/busy.gif>')";
  return false;"
>
```

I get a response; however, jQuery scripts don't work with an arrived code. I'm trying to add `script` inside `response_ajax.php`, but nothing happens:

```
<?php

// ... //

echo '

  <div id="whois-response">
    <pre>' .$str. '</pre>
  </div>

  <script>
    (function($){
      $(function(){
        alert("loaded");
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

';  

?>
```

---

`xmlhttpPost` function:

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL,formname,responsediv,responsemsg) {

    var xmlHttpReq = false;

    var self = this;

    // Xhr per Mozilla/Safari/Ie7

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    }

    // per tutte le altre versioni di IE

    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);

    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

            // Quando pronta, visualizzo la risposta del form

            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText,responsediv);

        }

        else{

            // In attesa della risposta del form visualizzo il msg di attesa

            updatepage(responsemsg,responsediv);



        }

    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname));

}


function getquerystring(formname) {

    var form = document.forms[formname];

    var qstr = "";



    function GetElemValue(name, value) {

        qstr += (qstr.length > 0 ? "&" : "")

            + escape(name).replace(/\+/g, "%2B") + "="

            + escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B");

            //+ escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\n/g, "%0D");

    }



    var elemArray = form.elements;

    for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {

        var element = elemArray[i];

        var elemType = element.type.toUpperCase();

        var elemName = element.name;

        if (elemName) {

            if (elemType == "TEXT"

                    || elemType == "TEXTAREA"

                    || elemType == "PASSWORD"

                    || elemType == "BUTTON"

                    || elemType == "RESET"

                    || elemType == "SUBMIT"

                    || elemType == "FILE"

                    || elemType == "IMAGE"

                    || elemType == "HIDDEN")

                GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);

            else if (elemType == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked)

                GetElemValue(elemName, 

                    element.value ? element.value : "On");

            else if (elemType == "RADIO" && element.checked)

                GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);

            else if (elemType.indexOf("SELECT") != -1)

                for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {

                    var option = element.options[j];

                    if (option.selected)

                        GetElemValue(elemName,

                            option.value ? option.value : option.text);

                }

        }

    }

    return qstr;

}


function updatepage(str,responsediv){

    document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;

}
```

Comment: What is xmlhttpPost? Some magical code?

Comment: what do you want ?execute alert("loaded")?

Comment: @epascarello What do you have against magic code?!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with the ajax response?  Do you have any code that processes the ajax response?  What is `xmlhttpPost()`?

Comment: @epascarello Added it to my post.

Comment: @jfriend00 Added it to my post.

Comment: tl;dr I suggest you look at the jQuery Form plugin. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Assigning to `innerHTML` doesn't run scripts that are inserted. Use `$.load()` -- it scans the result and for scripts and calls `eval()` to run them.

Comment: Why do you have the `jquery` tag when you seem to be going out of your way to roll your own instead of using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't do multiline strings unless it is configured to do so (and running a newer version of PHP):

```
echo '

  <div id="whois-response">
    <pre>' .$str. '</pre>
  </div>

  <script>
    (function($){
      $(function(){
        alert("loaded");
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

';
```

Try changing that to:

```
echo <<<EOD

  <div id="whois-response">
    <pre> $str </pre>
  </div>

  <script>
    (function($){
      $(function(){
        alert("loaded");
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

EOD;
```

I think your AJAX response is a PHP error instead of the script you think it is returning.

Comment: Thanks; however, there is no PHP error. Anyway, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by adding jQuery staff as a function

```
function updatepage(str,responsediv){

    document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;

    (function($){
      $(function(){
        $('html').my_jQuery_staff();
      });
    })(jQuery);

}
```

Main  JavaScript file with jQuery:

```
// ~~ jQuery ~~
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.my_jQuery_staff= function() {   
      return this.each(function() {   

        // Include jQuery staff here.

      });   
    };

    $('html').my_jQuery_staff();

});
```